# Jquery stop form submission on same page

Tags: jquery, submit

I have a form within a php page. And I want to stop it's submission with jquery for validation purposes.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
        alert('submitting');
        return false;
    });
```

Now this works just fine, if I try to send the form to another page. But if I write the php side validation and insertion codes on the same page as the form (with form's `action=""`), the page refreshes on submit and the data gets inserted in db.....any way to stop this? or do I have to use two separate pages for form and serverside validation/insertion ?

Comment: So which is the one doing the validation? jQuery or PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how much it could help, but for validation I use to hook an handler on the submit button instead of the form's submit event.

I mean that if you have in your HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
...
   <input type="submit" id="submit-button" />
</form>
```

on your javascript you will have:

```
$("#submit-button").click(function(e) {
   if (!valid()) { // you have a method that performs validation
      e.preventDefault(); // calling preventDefault is better than "return false"
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.